# PHP Issue "Fatal error: Call to a member function Save() on a non-object"

Tags: php, class, mysqli

I got this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function Save() on a non-object in line no 140"

In PHP editor it was like

```
$imageObj = split & new Image($row_image);
$imageObj->Save();
```

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: So what *does* $imageObj evaluate to? It's not "an object" as per the error message.

Answer (score 0):

What is this "split"  in `$imageObj = split & new Image($row_image);`?

try to change it to `$imageObj = new Image($row_image);` or explain what the use of it